# Is it possible/How can I select in the functions window the current subroutine in the IDA View?

Tags: ida

I'm in the IDA View-A within a subroutine. I've identified the subroutine, and now I want to navigate to the subroutine in the functions window so that I can jump around some of the other subroutines in the vicinity rather quickly.

I know that I can search the functions window with <kbd>Alt + T</kbd>, but I was wondering if there was a shortcut to automatically jump to the currently selected subroutine.

There are more than 200,000 subroutines in the functions window, so searching is slow.

Is it possible to navigate directly to the current subroutine, or to navigate directly to a subroutine based on address? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `ctrl-P` it will take you to the `"Choose function to jump to"` window which sounds like what you want.